# Error when installing the "Minkowski fractal dimension calculator" Plugin in QGIS 3

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, qgis-plugins, repository

I have tried to install the Minkowski fractal dimension calculator via the QGIS Plugin Repository, but got this error shown in the screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Please add the error messages as text, not picture.

Comment: What does  `QSettings().value('locale/userLocale')` return in QGIS Python Console?

Answer (score 3):

- Navigate to `PLUGIN_PATH/minkowskiDimCalculator` folder using `Settings > User Profiles > Open Active Profile Folder`.
- Open `minkowskiDimCalculator.py` file.
- Remove these lines:

  ```
  locale = QSettings().value('locale/userLocale')[0:2]
  locale_path = os.path.join(
      self.plugin_dir,
      'i18n',
      'MinkowskiDimCalculator_{}.qm'.format(locale))

  if os.path.exists(locale_path):
      self.translator = QTranslator()
      self.translator.load(locale_path)

      if qVersion() > '4.3.3':
          QCoreApplication.installTranslator(self.translator)
  ```
- Save the file, reopen QGIS, and try again. It worked for me.

Modifying the plugin's code is not a recommended method, but it can be helpful.